# Simple jQuery left/right slide toggle animation for mobile menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a menu that slides in and out from the right hand side of the screen for a mobile version of a site.

I have a 'ul' that starts off screen on page load due to its large margin. The plan is to have a button that will toggle that margin back and forth with '.animate' in order to hide and reveal the 'ul'.

The first chunk of code below works but won't repeat. So, on 'click', the menu appears, hides and then appears once more before it stops responding. This confused me so I tried a different route and went with an 'if' statement but now it just keeps sliding left despite the class definitely changing (i've checked it in the console).

Now i'm stumped! Can anyone help?

```js
// MOBILE MENU
$(function() {
 // create identical menu buttons with different classes 
 var $active = $("<div class='mm-active'><hr><hr><hr></div>");
 var $inactive = $("<div class='mm-inactive'><hr><hr><hr></div>");
  
 // append 'inactive' menu button to menu div
 $(".mobile-menu").prepend($inactive);

    $($inactive).click(function() {
     $($inactive).hide();
     $(this).next("ul").animate({'margin-left': '-='+90}, 1000);
     $(".mobile-menu").prepend($active);
 });

 $($active).click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll("ul").animate({'margin-left': '+='+90}, 1000);
  $($active).remove();
  $($inactive).show();
 });
});

//And here with the 'if' statement...

$(function() {
 // create identical menu buttons with different classes 
 var $mm_btn = $("<div><hr><hr><hr></div>");
 var $classname = ($mm_btn).attr("class");

 // append mobile menu button to menu div
 $(".mobile-menu").prepend($mm_btn);

 $($mm_btn).click(function() {
  $($mm_btn).toggleClass('active');

  if($classname === 'active') {
   $(this).next("ul").animate({'margin-left': '+='+90}, 1000);
  } else {
   $(this).next("ul").animate({'margin-left': '-='+90}, 1000);    
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.mobile-menu {
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 right: 0;
 width: 25px;
 margin: 0 25px 0 0;
 padding: 5px 0 8px 5px;
 z-index: 1;
}

.mobile-menu hr {
 border: 0;
 height: 2px;
 background: black;
}

.mobile-menu ul {
 position: relative;
 z-index: -1;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: right;
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-top: -50px;
 padding: 50px 25px 5px 5px;
 list-style: none;
}

.mobile-menu ul li {
 padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-menu">
 <ul>
  <a href="projects.html"><li class="projects">projects</li></a>
  <a href="about.html"><li>about</li></a>
  <a href="contact.html"><li>contact</li></a>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first case, when you are removing element all events are also removed: [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

In second case: `$classname` was set to empty string on page load and is never changed this is why only `else` is executed.

```js
// MOBILE MENU
$(function() {
  // create identical menu buttons with different classes 
  var $active = $("<div class='mm-active'><hr><hr><hr></div>");

  // append 'inactive' menu button to menu div
  $(".mobile-menu").prepend($active);

  $($active).click(function() {

    if ($active.hasClass('mm-active')) {
      $(this).nextAll("ul").animate({
        'margin-left': '-=' + 90
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $(this).nextAll("ul").animate({
        'margin-left': '+=' + 90
      }, 1000);
    }
    $active.toggleClass('mm-active');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mobile-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 0;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0 25px 0 0;
  padding: 5px 0 8px 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.mobile-menu hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}
.mobile-menu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding: 50px 25px 5px 5px;
  list-style: none;
}
.mobile-menu ul li {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-menu">

  <ul>
    <a href="projects.html">
      <li class="projects">projects</li>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html">
      <li>about</li>
    </a>
    <a href="contact.html">
      <li>contact</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: lukbl, you are the proverbial G, works like a dream, thank you.